# map form fields to POST data

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to consume a POST request from an external server, not from my application client. The request has this body:

```
ToCountry=US&ToState=CA&SmsMessageSid=SM4047b31943de6a4e6f78c9328a069daf...
```

For that I have created a form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    to_country = forms.CharField()
    to_state = forms.CharField()
    sms_message_sid = forms.CharField()
    ...
```

How do I tell Django that the form's `to_country` field should be populated from the `ToCountry` data item, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
if request.method == "POST":

    initial = { 
                     'to_country' : request.POST.get('ToCountry'),
                       'to_state' : request.POST.get('ToState'),
                'sms_message_sid' : request.POST.get('SmsMessageSid'),
                #rest of the fields
              }
    form = MyForm(initial=initial)
    #more code here.
```